# Paypal IPN verification with node.js - express app

Tags: node.js, paypal, express, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox

I am trying to implement Paypal IPN verification in my node.js app.I am using express framework.

This is my code :

```
app.post('/paypal', function(req,res){
console.log("IN PAYPAL !! req.body : "+req.body);
var ipn = require('paypal-ipn');
ipn.verify(req.body, function callback(err, msg) {
      if (err) {
        console.log("Error:"+err);
      } else {
        //Do stuff with original params here
          console.log("req.body.payment_status :"+req.body.payment_status+" msg: "+msg);
          res.end();
        if (req.body.payment_status == 'Completed') {
          //Payment has been confirmed as completed

        }
      }
    });
});
```

I am using [paypal-ipn](https://github.com/andzdroid/paypal-ipn) for this.

When I try to send the IPN message from Paypal Sandbox I am getting this message

> IPN delivery failed. Unable to connect to the specified URL. Please verify the URL and try again.

But when I try a sample message from terminal with the help of curl i am getting the request at my server app and it is displaying the log

> IN PAYPAL !! req.body : [object Object]
>   req.body.payment_status :Pending msg: VERIFIED
>   POST /paypal 200 572ms

Comment: From Paypal Sandbox I use the url as http://myserverurl:PORTNO/paypal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it. I am not listening to port 443 (https) in my server.

```
var https = require('https'),
    fs = require('fs');

var httpsOptions = {
    key: fs.readFileSync('path/to/private/key'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('path/to/certs')
}

http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function() {
    console.log("server listening on port " + app.get('port'));
});

https.createServer(httpsOptions, app).listen(443,function () {
    console.log("server listening on port " + 443);
});
```

Paypal sending the IPN message to the https port 443 (I think). Anyway I got it...

Comment: If i have already a ssl cert and key for my site how i can add the ipn certs and key to my httpsOptions ?